# How to redirect where an app read/save its file?

Tags: android, hook, frida

I have an application running on an Android 12 emulator that saves its settings to `/data/data` and its downloaded files to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/`.

By "*downloaded files*", I am referring to the files necessary for its operation, which are downloaded after the first execution.

I am attempting to configure it to save and load these files from a folder that the emulator shares with Windows, generally referred to as ***"shared folder"***.

The total size of these files is approximately 6GB, and my goal is to avoid duplicating these files for each emulator, enabling them all to read from the same folder.

The application does not provide an option to move this data to the SD card, I have checked this by looking at `settings > app > storage`.

I tried hooking the app using **Frida**:

```
frida -U -p <system_server_pid> -l tracker.js

var functionsToHook = ['open', 'fopen', 'stat'];

function applyHooks(session) {
  functionsToHook.forEach(function(func) {
      Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, func), {
          onEnter: function(args) {
              try {
                var path = Memory.readCString(ptr(args[0]));
                if (path.includes('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/')) {
                    console.log('\n\n', func, path);
                    console.log(Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE).map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).join('\n'));
                }
              } 
              catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
              }
          }
      });
  });
}
```

; however, it seems the app has some form of anti-hook or anti-debug, as it crashes when it reach the login page.
It crashes even with an empty js script.

Until the point of the crash, i could see that `console.log` is printing the mentioned folder and
the app is reading it using **"stat"** and a **custom** library:

```
stat /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...
0x7baaa055725d libabc.so!0x5125d
```

I attempted using the same script to hook the **system_server** process,
but as the app is using a custom lib to read the folder the hook on the server is not capturing it.

Is it possible to achieve this desired behavior by hooking into any other process or specific function?

My intention is to redirect the app to search for its file into the shared folder.

Comment: Before using Frida have you considered to redirect the directory using Linux soft links? According to this question I'd may be possible: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203951/2241

Comment: @Robert i created the link but then the apk misbehave

Answer (score 1):

For testing if the app has a anti-hook or anti-debug functions present connect with Frida without any script.

regarding your Frida script: You are hooking the six methods ´open´, `fopen`, `read`, `write`, `close`, `stat` and based on your Frida code you assume that each function gets the file path as C-String in the first argument (`args[0]`) - which is not the case.

- [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) first argument is `char*` -> no problem
- [`fopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) first argument is `char*` -> no problem
- [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) first argument is a file descriptor (`int`) -> code will crash
- [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) first argument is a file descriptor (`int`) -> code will crash
- [`close`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) first argument is a file descriptor (`int`) -> code will crash
- [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) first argument is `char*` -> no problem

So you can see that there are three hooked methods which will not work and most likely crash the app because you make wrong assumptions on the argument type.
So you should remove these hooks from your code.

```
var functionsToHook = ['open', 'fopen', 'stat'];

functionsToHook.forEach(function(func) {
    Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, func), {
        onEnter: function(args)  {
            try {
                var path = Memory.readCString(); // readUtf8String would also be an option
                console.log("path:", path);
                if (path.includes('/data/media/0/android/data'))
                    console.log(func + ' called on folder: ' + path);
            } 
            catch (e) {
            //console.log('Error reading memory:', e);
            }
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Ruan Sorry but no. I only answer question here on Stackexchange.  I don't offer private help.

Comment: Sorry, I am also not available as freelancer. Do the printen paths look totally scrambled, or just partially. So may be the string is not a CString but an UTF-8 String, so using `readUtf8String` would be an option. Note: I removed the length from my posted code as it worked different than I had in mind.

Comment: Hi Robert, please revise your answer, i have been able to collect more info about this issue, also readCString() doesnt print anything, the way i post on my question `var path = Memory.readCString(args[0]);` does.